# Picture of a closed window

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can you take a photo of Grid content in a closed window?

The content is generated in the constructor.

Creates an object of a given class that also contains a method for generating an image.

Calls a function but returns a black background (Metro). He does not see the contents of the window.

In the new window I have charts, which I want to take a picture and save to PNG. Operation without opening the window with graphs by the user.

Is this an operation possible to do?

Comment: Which type of app it is ? WinRT ? UWP ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's really what you want but, have you tried that:
In UWP you can try this (**rendering an UI Element into a Bitmap**):

```
private async void SaveImageSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{                        
...
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(); 
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderedGrid, width, height); 
    RenderedImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap; 
}
```

where 'RenderedGrid' is a grid (with some UIelements content) we want to render...

See documentation here:
[UWP Render target bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap)